# Content assist on pointcut definition using Eclipse and AspectJ (AJDT)

Tags: eclipse, aspectj, content-assist, ajdt

I was wondering if there is a way to activate the auto completion on the primitive pointcut definition in eclipse. It is very annoying to write the full qualified name of a class method by hand.

Answer (score 1):

Nope.  This is not implemented.

Comment: IMO, this is a perfectly reasonable answer, even if it is not the answer that @Jack is looking for.  He asked if it is possible... and I said, no it is not possible... (more precisely, it is not implemented, but it can be if someone wants to submit a patch).

Comment: sorry it's my bad I missunderstood it :)

Comment: @AndrewEisenberg: You as one of the main committers on AJDT probably know best about the project's priorities. Is this something you intend to implement anytime soon? I have been waiting for this for a few years as well.

Comment: I'm not working on the project anymore, but I do know that this is a feature that would be great to have. However, we never had the resources to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

An old question with good news. This has finally been implemented in AJDT 1.98 and Eclipse Neon 4.6.